# Setting select picker "val" to two options

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I currently have restrictions set in my model to only allow two options, out of 5, to be picked in a select picker if there is a check box checked.

Prior to allowing this second option we used "val" to restrict it to only one. Is there a way to do this with two options?

Here's what I'm thinking, with example 3 being the one I need two options for:

```
if (check_box.prop("checked")) {
      example1.selectpicker("val", "Option");
      example2.selectpicker("val", "Option");
      example3.selectpicker("val", "Option1")|| example3.selectpicker("val", "Option2");
      disable([example1, example2]);
    } else {
      enable([example1, example2]);
    }
```

But this locks it to only allowing "Option1" to be selected. What is the best approach to solving this and allowing it to pick both option1 and option2

****Here's an update on where I'm at

```
 if (check_box.prop("checked")) {
      example1.selectpicker("val", "Option");
      example2.selectpicker("val", "Option");
      example3.selectpicker('refresh');
      example3.find('[value="Option3"]').remove();
      example3.find('[value="Option4"]').remove();
      example3.find('[value="Option5"]').remove();
      disable([example1, example2]);
    } else {
      example3.find('[value="Option3"]').show();
      example3.find('[value="Option4"]').show();
      example3.find('[value="Option5"]').show();
      service.selectpicker('refresh');
      enable([example1, example2, example3]);
    }
```

The issue that I'm having now is getting the options to reappear after the check box has been unselected

Comment: `example3` makes no sense, but who knows what `selectpicker` is. Is it Bootstrap?

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that. Yeah, its using bootstrap.

Comment: Don't remove the elements - toggle the `disabled` attribute instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got the desired behavior:

```
    if (checkbox.prop("checked")) {
      example1.selectpicker("val", "Option");
      example2.selectpicker("val", "Option");
      example3.find('[value="Option3"]').hide();
      example3.find('[value="Option4"]').hide();
      example3.find('[value="Option5"]').hide();
      example3.selectpicker('refresh');
      disable([example1, example2]);
    } else {
      example3.find('[value="Option3"]').show();
      example3.find('[value="Option4"]').show();
      example3.find('[value="Option5"]').show();
      example3.selectpicker('refresh');
      enable([example1, example2, example3]);
    }
```